# how to change variable via AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need advice with AJAX.

I have page where i use to show info in block like:

```
<div1 container>
   <div2>
      some data
   </div2>
   <div3>
    <?php echo $variable;?>
   </div3>
</div>
```

and have another page that produce data:

```
function example( $array )
{
   ...some code...
return $answer
}

$variable = example($array);
```

i am sending AJAX query with some POST data from form and i need after operations  get new variable and put it in same  new params.

Here is my AJAX function:

```
function sendDataChild(btn) {
var form = $(btn).closest('FORM[name=answer-form]');
var data = form.serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get.php",
    dataType: "post",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        form[0].reset();
        //document.location.reload();
    },
    error: function (xhr, str) {
        alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
    }
});
return false;};
```

when i clear // and just reload page it works, but it is wrong way cause my page is quite big.
Can some body advise how to make it?

Comment: Can we see your actual html? Because <div1> is invalid syntax.

Comment: Your returned value is in the `data` attribute of your success function, try debugging that and see if it holds what you expect. Also `dataType: "post"` this is invalid, I guess jQuery will find it's way around this but have a look at the .ajax() api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the success function to output the data into the div where you want the variable to show:

```
success: function (data) {
    form[0].reset();
    $("#divId").html(data);
}
```

Comment: so i need to write something like exit html($variable)?

Answer (score 1):

Give a id to the div where you want to show the result

```
<div id="div3">

</div>
```

And you need to change your ajax

```
 function sendDataChild(btn) {
var form = $(btn).closest('FORM[name=answer-form]');
var data = form.serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get.php",
    dataType: "post",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $('div3').html(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, str) {
        alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: so i need to write something like 
exit html($variable)?

Comment: you can echo the $variable

Answer (score 0):

HTML page

```
<div1 container>
   <div2>
      <!--some data-->
   </div2>
   <div3 id="div3">

   </div3>
</div>
```

PHP page

```
function example( $array )
{
   //...some code...
   echo $answer;
   exit;
}
```

And your JavaScript

```
function sendDataChild(btn) {
var form = $(btn).closest('FORM[name=answer-form]');
var data = form.serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get.php",
    dataType: "post",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $('div3').html(data);
    }
});
}
```